# Can't update to symfony/service-contracts 3 even when all its dependencies have ^2|^3

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have a symfony 6 project and after running composer outdated I found out that I'm using symfony/service-contracts 2.5.1 when I should be able to update to 3.0

Here's my composer outdated output:

```
$ composer outdated --no-ansi
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Legend:
! patch or minor release available - update recommended
~ major release available - update possible
psr/container             1.1.2  ~ 2.0.2  Common Container Interface (PHP FIG PSR-11)
symfony/service-contracts v2.5.1 ~ v3.0.1 Generic abstractions related to writing services
```

If I execute `composer why symfony/service-contracts`:

```
$ composer why symfony/service-contracts        
doctrine/doctrine-bundle      2.6.1   requires  symfony/service-contracts (^1.1.1|^2.0|^3)    
symfony/cache                 v6.0.6  requires  symfony/service-contracts (^1.1|^2|^3)        
symfony/console               v6.0.7  requires  symfony/service-contracts (^1.1|^2|^3)        
symfony/dependency-injection  v6.0.7  requires  symfony/service-contracts (^1.1.6|^2.0|^3.0)  
symfony/doctrine-bridge       v6.0.7  requires  symfony/service-contracts (^1.1|^2|^3)        
symfony/security-core         v6.0.7  requires  symfony/service-contracts (^1.1.6|^2|^3)
```

So looks like it should be able to use the version 3 but for some reason it's stuck at 2.5.1. It's not a direct dependency on my composer.json so if I run `composer update symonfy/service-contracts` composer does nothing.

Any idea on why is it using 2.5 instead of 3?

Comment: Please, provide your `composer.json` so we can try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Probably has something to do with psr/container which should be at 2.0.2.  Did you manually update composer.json from Symfony 5?  Consider creating a new S6 project and then using it's composer.json as a starting point.

Comment: What does `composer why-not symfony/service-contracts 3.0.1` print?

Comment: @NicoHaase thank you! I found the issue thanks to your tip!

Answer (score 0):

OK, problem found...
I'm also using behat/behat and that requires psr/container ^1 (there's an open issue to use 2 in github). So that's why it can't use v3.
Thanks Nico Haase for the why-not tip!